# When are validators called in rails?During,before,or after the call to .create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to do some manipulations before a validation is called.(I need to set a value received from an api call before the field I want is validated).

Comment: use `before_validation` read this [Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

The relevant ones for you are:

- before_validation
- validate
- after_validation